# Laravel not letting me add styles to my Form::text()

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

This is my code for the form builder, and when I remove the array from the text() everything is fine, but when I add it I get this error

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 454: htmlentities() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:
>   /Users/samir/Sites/elicant/resources/views/pages/classes.blade.php)

```
{!! Form::open(array("url" => 'addClass', "method" => 'post')) !!}
{!! Form::text('classname', array('style' => 'width:80%;')) !!}
{!! Form::text('classcolour') !!}
{!! Form::submit("Add") !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/155/creating-a-text-input-field). This site is pretty handy for matters like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Form::text` has 3 parameters: `$name`, `$value`, `array $options = array()`
So to make your code working:

```
{!! Form::text('classname', null, array('style' => 'width:80%;')) !!}
```

Comment: Thank you, so very, very much. I understand now, gosh that was a pain. I really appreciate it :)